# How to update a multi-dimensional array with an object on a boardgame

Tags: javascript, oop, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a boardgame using oop in javascript. (very new to oop).
The idea is to have a multi-dimensional array with objects represented by a value or id.
I have made a multi-dimensional array to be the board.
I have created an object for the players as an example.
I can't seem to find a way to:

1. add the player (and other objects) to the board itself
2. add the player (and other objects) in a random spot on the board

```
createPlayers() {
  for (let i = 0; i < players; i++) {
    let players = [new Player("Player 1", 1),
      new Player("Player 2", 2)
    ];
    players.push(m);
  }
}
```

I've tried using push() in a for loop but I'm not sure if this is correct or anywhere close.

this is what i have that works:

```js
class Board {
  constructor(rows, cols) {
    let Board = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      Board[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        Board[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }
    return Board
  }
}

let m = new Board(10, 10);

class Player {
  constructor(name, id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
  }
}

let players = [new Player("Player 1", 1),
  new Player("Player 2", 2)
];
```

I get this far - no problem, when I console.table(m) the array shows with 0 as the default

The aim is to have the object (player) represented in the array as the number 1 and 2 and in a random spot.

I can get a random 1's to appear using

```
board[i][j] = (Math.random() * 2 | 0) + 0;
```

in the for loop for the board. but this is fairly useless at this stage as I can't seem to work out how to update the array.
any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a loop.  If you want to randomly place the two players on the board, that's two iterations of randomly picking an `i` and `j` for each player, within the confines of the board ranges.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Board {
  constructor(rows, cols) {
    let Board = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      Board[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        Board[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }
    return Board
  }
}

let totalRows = 10;
let totalCols = 10;
let m = new Board(totalRows, totalCols);

class Player {
  constructor(name, id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
  }
}

let players = [
  new Player("Player 1", 1),
  new Player("Player 2", 2)
];

players.forEach(function(player){
  let row, col, notInserted = true;
  
  while (notInserted) {
    row = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) % totalRows;
    col = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) % totalCols;
    
    if (m[row][col] === 0) {
      m[row][col] = player.id;
      notInserted = false;
    }
  }
});

console.log(m);
```

Once you have created the board and the players, loop over each player. For each player, get a random row and column number inside the boundary of the board.  If that position on the board is `0`, set the player there.  If it is not `0`, repeat the random number logic to get another position and continue until one is found that is `0`.